# Can't seem to add text to an H1 tag using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried everything on this website, on every website, but for some odd reason, I can't seem to add text to an h1 tag. I've done this a million times before no issues but now it doesn't seem to work no matter what I do. 
The onClick functions work perfectly fine tho, so I know the function is being ran.

```
    const true1 = document.getElementsByClassName('True')
    const false1 = document.getElementsByClassName('False')
    const next = document.getElementsByClassName('next')
    const questione = document.getElementById('QuestionE')


function questionOne(){
      questione.innerHTML = "hello";

        true1[0].addEventListener('click', ((() => function aClickEvent(){
            true1[0].classList.toggle('TrueH')
             next[0].classList.toggle('nextS')
             }))(), false);

             false1[0].addEventListener('click', ((() => function aClickEvent(){
             false1[0].classList.toggle('FalseH')
             next[0].classList.toggle('nextS')
            }))(), false);

    }

   window.addEventListener('load', questionOne(), false);
```

Comment: What is with the self executing functions that return a function?

Comment: @AdrianBrand What do you mean? Talking about the window.addEventListener?

Comment: (() => function() {})() this is a self executing function that returns a function, you could just write function() {}

Comment: When you've added a [mcve] that **reproduce the issue described**, and it should be **within** the question, someone will be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', questionOne(), false);
```

this is calling questionOne which returns nothing so you function is executing imediately before the DOM is there and you are attaching undefined as the function to call on load.

Try

```
window.addEventListener('load', questionOne, false);
```

Without the calling parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah nothing, onClick functions still works that way but, still doesn't add the "hello" to the h1 tag

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to write immediately invoked function expressions, ie

```
(function blah(){})()
```

is this what you mean to do? You have click listeners, so maybe you meant something like this:

```
function questionOne() {
  questione.innerHTML = "hello";

  true1[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    true1[0].classList.toggle('TrueH')
    next[0].classList.toggle('nextS')
  }, false);

  false1[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    false1[0].classList.toggle('FalseH')
    next[0].classList.toggle('nextS')
  }, false);

}
```

btw 'hello' appears in my test...

Comment: Yeah that makes the onClick functions a little simpler and less cluttered, but it still doesn't help with the .innerHTML. The onClick functions work just fine

Comment: and exactly, it makes no sense it's not showing up in mine, there are no errors, everything is spelt correctly, its driving me crazy lol

Comment: Just had a thought - you are loading your script after the html has loaded, or doing something like: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
});

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works so I am assuming that you have incorrectly spelled QuestionE in the id as I cannot see your markup or the

```
const questione = document.getElementById('QuestionE')
```

runs before The element exists in the DOM. Try putting the line in the function or console.log(questione) and see if it has a value.

```js
const questione = document.getElementById('QuestionE')

function questionOne(){
  questione.innerHTML = "hello";
}

window.addEventListener('load', questionOne, false);
```

```html
<div id="QuestionE"></div>
```

Comment: <h1 id="QuestionE"></h1>  Yeah no its spelt correctly, just magically doesn't work lol

Comment: Where is the script, what I quess is happening is that the document.getElementById('QuestionE') is being run before the DOm has the h1 in it. Try moving the document.getElementById('QuestionE') into the function as that is run after load.

Comment: Just tried it and nothing :/. I'm so confused right now